# Eclipse has set a directory as derived and I cannot turn it off

Tags: django, eclipse, git

I have a django project in eclipse, and I am using git as the repository.  I have looked online for an answer, and I can't find one.  I have suddenly discovered that one entire directory of my templates has been marked as derived, and it seems that new files in the directory are not being committed/pushed to the repository.  I have opened the properties window for this directory several times, and unchecked the derived checkbox, clicked save, and the change is not saved.  The next time I open the properties for this directory, it is marked as derived.  With even brand new files I get the warning that the file is derived, do I want to edit it.  And the files do not appear in git.  I need to turn this off.  It is still there when I restart eclipse.  These are normal django template files, they are not derived from anything, and I need them in the project.  What am I doing wrong?

Eclipse Neon version 4.6.0

Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Ok, eclipse has let go, somehow.  I restarted it again, now the directory is not marked as derived.  Now I only need to make my changes visible to git...that is still not happening.

Comment: ok, I did a git add -f for my two orphaned files, and they are now in git.

Comment: Derived resources are automatically added to `.gitignore` and therefore the files were not visible in Git.